# Identical code but throws NullPointerException in ZK JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, zk

I'm working on a project that uses Spring (Spring MVC) and Hibernate, both latest versions. For frontend I'm using Zk 6.5.0. Here is the problem:

I have a controller like this:

```
public class SearchController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @WireVariable("MjestaAutoComplete")
    private AutoComplete<Mjesta> mjesta;

    @Listen("onChanging = #mj")
    public void autocomplete(InputEvent event) {    

        if (mjesta == null) {
            Messagebox.show("Mjesta == Null");
            return;
        } else {
            mjesta.doSomething();
        }            

    }

}
```

Zul page looks like this:

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<zk>
    <div apply="hr.restart.erp.web.controller.SearchController">
            <combobox id="mj" autocomplete="true" autodrop="true" />
    </div>
</zk>
```

Here's the jsp (just relevant part) using ZK JSP tags:

```
<z:variable-resolver use="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver" />
<z:page>
     <z:div apply="hr.restart.erp.web.controller.SearchController">
        <z:combobox id="mj" autocomplete="true" autodrop="true"></z:combobox>
     </z:div>
</z:page>
```

If I include zul page in jsp by jsp's include directive code executes normally that is "mjesta" is not null. If I remove directive and use zk jsp tags instead "mjesta" object is null. How can this be possible when code is identical? Only way I can explain this to myself is that "mjesta" is not getting autowired but that doesn't make much sense...
Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is, doing a bit of research now. In the interest of debugging, can you slap this annotation at the top of your SelectorComposer class definition?

@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)

Comment: Can you take out the variable-resolved tags in both and try with the annotation and let me know if either resolves the Spring bean using just the VariableResolver annotation.

Comment: Zul resolves it normally, JSP still null.

Comment: Hmm, K, so as not to get hung up on why one works and another doesn't, lets try and just figure out why exactly the one doesn't. In your SearchController add in some debug code like the following. Do you see your bean as you expect?
    for (String beanName: SpringUtil.getApplicationContext().getBeanDefinitionNames()){
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
System.out.println(SpringUtil.getBean("MjestaAutoComplete").toString();

Comment: One thing about ZK's VariableResolver is it is very dependent on names (unlike Spring). If you name your variable 'mjesta', your class must be named 'Mjesta'. If you provide a name to the resolver, like you do, it should probably be 'mjestaAutoComplete' if the class is named 'MjestaAutoComplete'. If this is the cause of your problems I'd like to figure out why it works fine in your other example.

Comment: I added the debug code you provided before and I can see bean clearly from both zul and jsp. Bean is listed as hr.restart.erp.web.autocomplete.MjestaAutoComplete@67cc3210. As for names I tried changing them and I even removed name from the @repository and it's still giving me null pointer from jsp. Zul is working as intended.

Comment: And hr.restart.erp.web.autocomplete.MjestaAutoComplete implements the interface AutoComplete<Mjesta>, yeah? Is MjestaAutoComplete an interface itself? Can you provide a skeleton of the MjestaAutoComplete code and any relevant classes/interfaces?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/1RGKbP0w

Comment: try

public class MjestaAutoComplete implements AutoComplete<Mjesta> extends AutoCompleteImpl<Mjesta>

Comment: I don't see how NPE can be thrown in your code, even if "mjesta" is null. Can you paste the stack trace to find out what line causes the NPE?

Comment: True, I believe Mirko has massaged the code a bit to boil it down to the essentials here. In his real code, I assume, he is getting an NPE when he tries to call mjesta.doSomething(). In the toy code here he does the null check which gets away from the NPE, but the problem is still why mjesta is null.

Comment: Hi Mirko, wanted to let you know I've been able to reproduce this bug on my side too. Still looking into it. It's looking like a bug though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe this is a bug.

**I've submitted a ticket to ZK [here](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1542).**

Removing as much dependency on either ZUL or ZKJSP, I was able to reproduce the issue with the VariableResolver in general.

I created `MyVariableResolver` like so:

```
public class MyVariableResolver implements VariableResolver {

    @Override
    public Object resolveVariable(String name) throws XelException {
        System.out.println("Resolving variable: " + name);
        return null;
    }

}
```

And attached it to the `MyController` like so:

```
@VariableResolver(MyVariableResolver.class)
public class MyController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @WireVariable
    public Object wireMePlease;

}
```

The ZUL file then becomes simply:

```
<div apply="MyController"/>
```

And the ZKJSP file is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/jsp/zul" prefix="z"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <z:page>
            <z:div apply="MyController"/>
        </z:page>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the ZUL file is evaluated, `MyVariableResolver` is called to fetch `wireMePlease`.

When the ZKJSP file is evaluated, however, `MyVariableResolver` is never called.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the comments, I think if you write

```
public SearchController(){
  AutoComplete<Mjesta> mjesta = SpringUtil.getBean("MjestaAutoComplete");
}
```

`mjesta` will not be null right? This should solve your problem regardless of
the reason of this behavior.
But, I guess the reason should be in config so that VariableResolver is not called
at thre right place. Best you check your config by compare it with the [zk doc](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spring%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring).

Comment: Eeh, that's a hack not a solution. This won't hold up well in tests or the like which WireVariable can be mocked.

Comment: Why do you think this is a hack and not a solution? Variable resolvers are not nessessary they just exist to make your life easier. Take a look at the (java doc)[http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zkplus/spring/SpringUtil.html] do you find a warning not to use this in production? Somtimes you cant not even choose to use variable resolver, cos variables are resolved in zks `doAfterCompose(..)`. So if you need to accsess a bean inside a object that is not a composer what would you like to do? Pass it from the composer to the underlying objects? This code will not be readable.

Comment: It is a hack because, as you said, 'this should solve your problem regardless of the reason of this behavior'. It's a solution without an understanding of the problem. As such, it cannot be an elegant solution except out of pure luck. ZK's Spring VariableResolver allows us to leverage the likes of Spring's @Autowire annotation in our ZK code. To use SpringUtil would be on par with reaching into the Spring context itself and grabbing classes. That just isn't clean.

Comment: Furthermore, and we're off topic now, wiring Spring beans are not limited to composers, or to doAfterCompose, and accessing a bean from 'inside an object' shouldn't ever be a problem if your code is organized well.

Answer (score 1):

here is a work around: **Call Selectors.wireVariables() manually in doAfterCompose().**

`public class SearchController extends SelectorComposer {`

```
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {

        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        Selectors.wireVariables(getPage(), this, _resolvers);

    }
```

}